# How to create a new column in pandas and add value to that new column based on the conditional value from the existing column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have got a data-frame with a-lot of encodings. I want to create a new column where I want to add string values based on the numbers from the first column of the dataset. For example if the first column in the dataset has numbers 0,1,2,3 and 4 then I want to add string 'Thor' in the same rows in the new column.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

So far I have tried:

```
def name_values(data):
    if(data['facefeat_1']==-0.141472) | (data['facefeat_1']== -0.141472) | (data['facefeat_1']== -0.221594) | (data['facefeat_1']== -0.181907) | (data['facefeat_1']== -0.184878):
        data['Name'] = 'Thor'
```

facefeat_1 being the name of the first column in dataframe and 'Name' being the new column I want to populate

**The desired output should be**

**Name**
Thor
Loki

**What I got:**
None
None

Screenshot:
[image]

**[image: Another screenshot]**

Comment: Please add an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Provide code samples with what you tried

Comment: done. Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a dataframe (df) which has a column facefeat_1, and based on the values of facefeat_1 column of a particular row you want the df.name value to be a string.
You can add a apply function in the following manner

```
def get_names(row):
    if row['facefeat_1'] in [-0.141472,-0.141472, -0.141472, -0.221594,-0.181907,-0.184878]:
        return "Thor"
    elif row['facefeat_1'] in some_list:
        return "Loki"
    else:
        return "Odin"
```

and then you can set df['name'] in the following manner

```
df['name'] = None
df['name'] = df.apply(get_names, axis = 1)
```

If you face any issue/error please send screenshots.

Comment: Hi there. I have tried this but for some reason, it doesn't add the strings in the newly created columns. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Can you show the desired output and current output? Attach a screenshot.

Comment: Not sure how to put screenshot in order to make sense but I have modified the question. Basically, I wanted the new coloumns to be populated with names like Thor and Loki but instead I have got None None in the new coloumn even after implementing the above code

Comment: Does the name column have none values for facefeat_1 in  [-0.141472,-0.141472, -0.141472, -0.221594,-0.181907,-0.184878] ? I am assuming you are using jupyter notebook, print the dataframe using display(df) and take screenshot so that the dataframe is visible.

Comment: I have added it. Since the dataframe is big so it won't display all the values in it. That's why I said 'Not sure how to put screenshot in order to make sense', however for your question, no there is no empty value in column facefeat_1

Comment: use the following code you will be able to see all the rows 
`pd.options.display.max_rows = 4000 #(change according to need)`
`pd.options.display.max_rows = 4000#(change accroding to need)`
if the name column is dependent only on facefeat_1 print only those columns
`df[['facefeat_1','name']]`

Comment: The screenshot won't cover all the data however, I. checked whether it has any empty values and it doesn't so I don't think it is a problem

Comment: I ahve tried it again. It doesn't work for some reason on mine. I have tried everything and it still doesn't work

Comment: @ShikharGhimire use `pd.options.display.max_rows = some large number` to avoid data truncations. And then use `display(df[['facefeat_1','name']])` to display the two columns and attach screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220351/discussion-between-shikhar-ghimire-and-r0ot293).